# I want to make a my batch program to read and write into a dll?

Tags: batch-file

Im make a little program for fun, and have come to a problem, when i run the program. I want to make it possible to write **SET cake = 100**
and then it's gonna be saved in a dll or a other batch file, and be called if back if writen cake
And press enter the console is going to write back **100**
Thanks for the help in front :D

Comment: A DLL file isn't a batch file.  It's a binary

Comment: Too vague, you cannot write in a dll.

Comment: If you want to manipulate a DLL, you'll probably have to use a lower level language like C to mess around with it on a binary (or hex notation) level, unless you use a library to decompile it into an object (C++), manipulate the object, and recompile the object back into the parent file during runtime.  There is no way to do this with Batch files.  Batch files are just running a bunch of commands.

Comment: aha thanks. I watched a video where he used a dll så save information
but he was making a game and used dll as save date.
so that why i thought that it was the way to go.

but thanks for the explanation help me to understandt it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may save the value of a variable in a file, and later return it in another Batch file. There are two common ways to do that. Via a text file:

```
rem Save the value
echo %cake%> saved.TXT

rem Get the value, in same or any other Batch file
set /P cake=< saved.TXT
```

... or via a Batch file

```
rem Save the value
echo set cake=%cake%> saved.BAT

rem Get the value, in same or any other Batch file
call saved
```

Antonio

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting confused about DLL's, you can't use them like that, but you can do what you want to do with just batch.

```
set cake=100
```

Then you can retrieve it using

```
%cake%
```

like

```
echo %cake%
```

However, that will only last as long as that cmd prompt/or batch file, is running. If you want to use it after this then you can use `setx` to set it as an environment variable.

```
setx cake 100
echo %cake%
```

Which will save it after the session has closed.

Hope this helps

Comment: oh okay but il like it to change in another batch file so it dossent change in the main batch i thought that that was what you used dll for  :)

Comment: You use Dll's for storing code, in languages like C++/C etc, not batch :) If you want to store it why don't you try storing it in a text file instead? `echo 100 >C:\cake.txt`

Comment: i just saw some one make a game in batch and he used a dll, to be a save data file, witch he saved and loaded on.

but thanks i think i get it now :)