# Using Visual Studio "Build Action" or Preprocessor directives to embed different Resource Files, Different Output Release Folder, and Sign by Script

Tags: c#, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I have an add-on application for vendor supplied application(APP) (Siemens NX CAD/CAM) with multiple versions.

For each version of the add-on, the build needs a different resource file, different release build folder, and digitally signed with a specific APP version utility.

Currently, I build with different resource files, move the .dll to a different folder, and run vendor supplied Version specific DotNet Signing .bat file on the .dll.

How could I build once for all versions and get all versions?

I'm looking at preprocessor directives, BuildAction properties, and is there a post directive to run a batch file?

Comment: Hello, do you want to get all versions of DotNet Signing .bat file at once? I don't quite understand what "all versions" means, specifically what all versions are.

Comment: Yes, but the .bat is supplied by a vendor, so each build would produce multiple (my case 5) .dll versions. It is not the MS DotNet Signing.

Comment: Here's a post about batch dlls that you can build upon.<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456781/i-want-to-make-a-my-batch-program-to-read-and-write-into-a-dll>